Finding solution of a nonlinear equation containing both the vector and its norm
While solving a convex optimization problem with a nasty subdifferential, I stumbled upon the nonlinear vector equation
$$ c \frac{w}{\| w \|_2} - u + A w = 0,$$
where $c$ is a positive constant, $w$ is a vector of interest, $u$ is some parameter vector, and $A$ is a positive definite matrix that is of form $A = \gamma Id + B$ with $B$ also PSD (in other words, we can say $A$'s eigenvalues are bounded from below).
I know that I don't have enough assumptions/information to solve this equation with respect to $w$.
However, I am now interested in just finding the norm of $w$ from this equation (for example in terms of the spectrum of $A$).
I have tried out different recursions like multiplying by $A^{-1}$ over and over and seeing if there is a limit. However, this is not bringing me anywhere.
Does anyone know how to approach a problem like this? Or can you maybe say that finding $\| w \|_2$ is impossible so that I stop wasting my time?
Thanks a lot!

try dotting with w

You can try decomposition of $u$ into eigenvectors of $A$

Let $s = \dfrac{w}{\|w\|_2},\; t = \|w\|_2$. Then
$$cs - u + tAs = 0 \Leftrightarrow (cI+tA)s = u$$
Suppose A is diagonalizable. Let $(\lambda_i)$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ and $(v_i)$ be the corresponding  eigenvectors. Then the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $cI+tA$ are $(t\lambda_i + c)$ and $(v_i)$. Thus $cI + tA$ is positive definite and
$s = (cI+tA)^{-1}u$
Let $Q = [\begin{matrix}v_1 &\cdots &v_n\end{matrix}]$, $\Lambda = \mathrm{diag}([\begin{matrix} \lambda_1 &\cdots & \lambda_n\end{matrix}])$ then
$$s = Q(t\Lambda + c)^{-1} Q^{-1} u $$
In other words, if we scale each component of $u$ (in its representation as linear combination of eigenvectors) by $\dfrac{1}{t\lambda_i + c}$, we get $s$. Given $s$ being unitary, we can find $t$ by solving
$$1 = \left \|\sum \frac{v_i u'_i}{t\lambda_i + c}\right\|_2$$
Where $u' = Q^{-1} u$
In case $A$ is not diagonalizable, then we have to the consider the Jordan normal form, which results in a bit more complicated equation, but still solvable.

Thanks for your response! As far as I see, solving the last equation in the general case is not possible without making further assumptions.

@convex-pineapple the last equation is solvable (numerically). It's polynomial of twice the degree of $A$.
